# How to check types in returned value in tests

Tags: python, pytest

I need to write test for my function. Now I check only type of my return:

```
assert type(main.get_values(path)) == list
```

Can I check somehow if returned value is not only `list`, but `list of strings`? I'm new with python, so it could be quite lame question.

Comment: As a programmer I would usually test the contents of a variable. This implicitly tests the types.

Comment: @quamrana, Like `== ['test', 'test2']`? Or how should I write it?

Comment: Yes, like that. I would normally provide some data to `main` such that when you get round to call `main.get_values(path)` in the assert, it will return `['test, 'test2']`

Comment: I created already new path with files and can just check it. It will be better for sure. As always answer is quite simple. Thanks

Comment: @quamrana, Can I ask you about one more thing? If I created that files, get path and write test looks like `== ['test', 'test2']`, but my function get values in another order (`['test2', 'test']`). Can I make it works whatever order it is??

Comment: If the order doesn't matter, then sort the return value: `assert sorted(main.get_values(path)) == ['test', 'test2']`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT:**
As quamrana mentioned, testing values implicitly verifies types and is what I would normally do as well. However, here is an answer to your original question.

Unlike certain array types in many languages, Python lists are allowed to contain any combination of data types. Therefore, the clearest (though cumbersome) way to achieve this is to check each value in the list to make sure it is a string. For example,

```
# Check to see if data is a list, as before
assert type(my_data) is list

# Now check each value in your data is a string
for value in my_data:
    assert type(value) is str
```

This will let your test pass if you have data like this

```
my_data = ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"]
```

But not if you have data like this

```
my_data = ["h", "e", 1, ["nested", "list"], {"dictionary":"here"}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Aside from the accepted answer, you can also do

```
 # Check to see if data is a list, as before
    assert isinstance(value, list)
```